# App Engine Deployment failing - BuildError - MemoryError - Deployment failed with exit code: 1

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment, google-cloud-platform

We are not able to deploy our app anymore to App Engine Standard.

Steps to reproduce: we simply deploy our project with IntelliJ IDEA - we get the following error:

```
Beginning deployment of service [default]...
#============================================================#
#= Uploading 0 files to Google Cloud Storage                =#
#============================================================#
File upload done.
Updating service [default]...
.................................................................................failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build 15c72c99-c2cc-4e4d-b910-0eee13a9cb5a status: FAILURE.
Error ID: 6AA2815A.
Error type: BuildError.
Error message: 21 Feb 2020 04:36:00 INFO     Running as user 0, group 0
21 Feb 2020 04:36:00 INFO     Arguments: ['--name=eu.gcr.io/XXXXXXX/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:af4f2b82-4138-4c9a-905f-6f9cf038e4cd', '--src=/workspace', '--base=eu.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/java8:java8_20191215_8_0_RC00']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/bin/appender.par/__main__.py", line 90, in <module>
  File "/bin/appender.par/__main__.py", line 76, in main
  File "/bin/appender.par/containerregistry/client/v2_2/append_.py", line 74, in __init__
  File "/bin/appender.par/containerregistry/client/v2_2/docker_image_.py", line 110, in uncompressed_blob
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 260, in read
    self._read(readsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 319, in _read
    self._add_read_data( uncompress )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 337, in _add_read_data
    self.extrabuf = self.extrabuf[offset:] + data
MemoryError.
Failed to deploy '[2020-02-21 06:33:21] XXXX:war exploded. Project: XXXXXX. Version: vvvv': Deployment failed with exit code: 1
Please make sure that you are using the latest version of the Google Cloud SDK.
Run ''gcloud components update'' to update the SDK. (See: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/components/update.)
```

The Cloud SDK is managed by IDEA .. it seems to be the latest version (in Settings - Cloud SDK).

We have another smaller test project in IDEA which we can deploy without issues.
And we have another larger project in Eclipse which fails with a similar error - MemoryError.

I guess there must be some Memory issue in Google Cloud since the smaller project works fine, but the 2 larger projects do not work!!

This happens since yesterday .. we searched but could not find any similar issues .. so I guess this must be something new?

**UPDATE:**

It seems to work now .. I guess it was a temporary glitch in the Google deployment process.

Answer (score 0):

For issues like this, it would be better to [open a ticket](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/procedures#create_a_support_case) to the Google Cloud Platform support team. They will be able to troubleshoot it better with access to the specifics of your environment and the logs.